# Redirect to current page PHP pagination

Tags: php, html

first of all, I'm sorry, I am new in this community also my English is not so good, I hope you guys will understand. The question I want to ask is

Currently I'm doing my directory website project, that display all the data in database in pagination because of the massive data in database. User need to select the the state and cluster, then the website will show the list of result. But all the list must be in pagination. I expected when click the page link, it will take the user to 2nd page and so on.

[current website display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drZu5.png)

But the actual result is, when I click the 2nd page, it shows nothing. Like this: [the website page after click 2nd page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txxIk.png)

I am still new in PHP code. I've tried everything I could. I would like to ask, is there something wrong in my coding?

here is some of my coding for "index.php"

```
enter code here




    <form method="post">
    <div class="input">
    <select name="state" class="btn" required>
      <option value="" class="placeholder" selected disabled>Carian Mengikut Negeri</option>
      <option value="Johor">Johor</option>
      <option value="Kedah">Kedah</option>
      <option value="Kelantan">Kelantan</option>
      <option value="Melaka">Melaka</option>
      <option value="Negeri Sembilan">Negeri Sembilan</option>
      <option value="Pahang">Pahang</option>
      <option value="Penang">Penang</option>
      <option value="Perak">Perak</option>
      <option value="Perlis">Perlis</option>
      <option value="Sabah">Sabah</option>
      <option value="Sarawak">Sarawak</option> 
      <option value="Selangor">Selangor</option>
      <option value="Terengganu">Terengganu</option>
      <option value="Wilayah Persekutuan">Wilayah Persekutuan</option>
    </select>

    <select name="cluster" class="btn" required>
      <option value="">Kluster Perniagaan</option>
      <option value="Makanan dan Minuman">Makanan & Minuman</option>
      <option value="Gaya Hidup">Gaya Hidup</option>
      <option value="Automotif">Automotif</option>
      <option value="Pembinaan">Pembinaan</option>
      <option value="Perkhidmatan">Perkhidmatan</option>
    </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cari" >
     </div>
  </form>

<div class="output">
  <?php
  include "connect.php";
   ?>
</div>
```

And here is my "connect.php" that has a query (sorry, i cant show the full code at code sample, so i use snippet)

```html
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bpuvirtu_Directory') or die("Connection Failed");


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{ 
  $result_per_page = 10;
  $str= $_POST["state"];
  $cluster=$_POST["cluster"];
  $sth="SELECT * FROM TABLE3 WHERE state='$str' and  service='$cluster'";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sth);    

  $number_of_results=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    

$number_of_results;
$number_of_pages= ceil($number_of_results/$result_per_page);


if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page=1;
}
else{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}


 $this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$result_per_page;
 
    $sth="SELECT * FROM TABLE3 WHERE state='$str' and  service='$cluster' LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . "," . $result_per_page;
 
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sth);
    
    ?>
      <table id="user">
      <tr>
        <th>Nama Syarikat</th>
        <th><center>Kluster</center></th>
        <th><center>Info</center></th>
      </tr>  <?php
    
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
        <tr>
          <form method="GET" action=detail.php>
          <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></center> </td>
          <td><center><?php echo $row["service"]; ?></center> </td>
          <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'/>
          <td><center><input type="submit" name="detail" value="Info" ></center></td>
        </form>
        </tr>
      <?php
        
        
    }?></table><?php
    
for($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++){
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a>';
}

    
}
?>
```

So, when I click page 2, I want it show the list from database at page 2.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values.

Comment: Print out the value of `$sth` and manually run that in a query tool to see what it returns

Comment: @ChrisHaas


Im sorry for my little knowledge, what do you mean by that?

As I showed at the question image, the result is print out at current website display, but when click for 2nd page, its not show anything

Comment: You should inspect the value of `$sth` to see what is actually in there. Whenever you dynamically create a string, small typos or incorrect logic can result in surprises. So after you create the string, do `echo $sth;` to see what was created. Then take that SQL and manually run it against the database, from the command line, phpMyAdmin, etc.

Comment: Now I the problem, the problem is from my '$sth' . That's why it show no result, Thankyou for the help, I think I need to reconstruct my code.   @ChrisHaas

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//$page =  grab page number from the query param here.
return redirect('currencies?page='.$page);
```

or:

```
$results->url($page)
```

Comment: where should I put this?